# How to generate schema.graphql in VS Code from config file

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql, webstorm

I have the following `graphql.config.json` in my root directory:

```json
{
  "name": "GraphQL Schema",
  "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
  "documents": "./**/*.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "GraphQL Parse Endpoint": {
        "url": "http://localhost:1337/graphql",
        "headers": {
          "X-Parse-Application-Id": "COOK_APP",
          "X-Parse-Master-Key": "MASTER_KEY_1"
        },
        "introspect": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In WebStorm, if I rename it to be `.graphqlconfig` (this name format is considered "legacy" for VS Code as far as I'm aware) I will have a run button that is going to get my `schema.graphql`.

[image]

How can I generate the same `schema.graphql` in the VS Code?